# importing csv into sqlite with sqlite3 gives me one row

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, csv

So I'm having trouble importing a csv into my sqlite table. My file looks to be fine: I specified in the `.separator` the `,\n` (the structure of my file). But when I import, there seems to be only one row, with all the content from the csv in there. I want it to import the file and have the sqlite3 put each value in its own row. What am I doing wrong?

**Table**

```
$ sqlite3 test
SQLite version 3.6.12
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table test (name text);
sqlite> .separator ,\n
sqlite> .import sqlite.csv test
sqlite> select * from test;
Biohazard,
Bird,
Black-Star,
Black-Truck,
Blog,
Boardwalk,
...
sqlite> select * from test where name="Bird";
sqlite> //notice here that nothing comes up for 'Bird'
//But what I want it to do is to return 'Bird' like so:
sqlite> select * from test where name="Bird";
Bird
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your separator to just `,`... the `\n` makes it look for a comma followed by a newline for every field separator.

```
.separator ,
```

Comment: I tried that, and then it gives an error: `line 1: expected 1 columns of data but found 2`

Comment: Ah, that is because when you initially import your table must have the same number of columns as the .csv file.  I sometimes import into a temporary table and then copy into a final table with my desired columns.

Comment: Got it! So what I did was made a table with two columns and imported the csv in. It also turned out I needed to add a comma at the last value, probably what was giving me all the trouble. Then I created a new table and imported the first column with all the data I needed. Thanks a lot!